# Fluid sim does not show up, even after baking

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I have a fluid sim set up with 2 inflows, and 2 out flows. The particles do not show up. I remade the inflows and the domain, but it still doesn't show up. I deleted a bunch of other stuff around because the file was over 500mb.

[.blend file](https://pasteall.org/blend/20482218979f438888df7af7845e1633)

Comment: Have you baked the mesh?

Comment: @Mysticreator sorry for the late response, yes.